# Making URL structure upto 4 or 5 level in wordpress for SEO purpose

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to make the URL structure up to 4 or 5 in WordPress?

Example:

```
http://www.volunteeringnepal.org/child_database/sponsor-an-orphan-child/gita-magar
```

When I go to single page of WordPress then it ends with 3 level of URL. I tried so hard to make it upto 4 level but couldn't succeed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra levels of 'folders' to a URL path by making a page a child of another page. If this isn't appropriate/still doesn't work for you try using this plugin which will allow you to set the permalink to whatever you want on a page-by-page basis: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: Thank you for ideas, I want to make parent child relationship in custom post type. and maintaining URL structure accordingly, it may be upto 4 or 5 levels . How can I maintain parent child relationship in custom post type without using any plugins.